# IntelliJ IDEA 12 setup for C/C++ on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, intellij-idea

I recently decided to try IntelliJ IDEA 12 CE.

I Successfully installed their C/C++ plugin and restarted the IDE.

Now after I click File->New Project->C/C++ Module, next window prompts me to "Choose Cpp SDK".

I'm stuck at this window, tried entering many paths and failed.
My system is OSX Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.5.2 with command-line tools installed.
Compiling from command line with gcc works just fine.

Comment: Did you read the manual? Did you contact the support of IntelliJ?

Comment: It's a 3rd party plugin, it's not made by JetBrains: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pr=idea_ce&pluginId=1373

Comment: I see now. According to comments in the plugins download page, they seem to have abandoned the project. Well, I'm gonna stick with NetBeans.

Comment: Is Xcode no good then? I do lots of C++ development with it, and find it excellent...

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that using Idea 12.0.1 Ultimate (Build Id 123.94) and Xcode 4.5.1 on OSX this simply works. At the dialog for "Choose Cpp SDK" I wrote /usr/bin/gcc (which was what "which gcc" returns on my system. I used version 0.8 build 4.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice C++/Obj-C IDE from JetBrains for development on OSX - AppCode. Not so long ago it updated to 2.0 version. Most IDEA functionality and plugins are supported.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is displayed when running IDEA from command line:

```
ERROR - com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue - Error during dispatching of java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_RELEASED,(449,630),absolute(903,739),button=1,modifiers=Button1,clickCount=1] on dialog0
```

Probably bug in the plugin for IDEA 12.

Try to use IDEA 11.